# Can't write in tcl command line unless sending echo, after using PLINK

Tags: ssh, tcl, prompt, plink

I'm having a confusing problem running a variety of programs from a tcl script. Here's the story: I have a script (in tcl) which executes plink to establish a remote connection on a Linux computer. I basically use eval for calling plink, sending as parameters some ssh commands and info, and also a bash file to be executed on the Linux computer.

So far, that works fine, or at least it does what I intend it to do. The issue here is that after calling this procedure, my prompt stops working the normal way. I can type, but it doesn't appear on screen unless the command I send is "echo" (without ""). If so, I get the "ECHO is on" message and the prompt continues to work normally.

Does anyone have any idea why this could be happening? I thought about just patch it and add the "echo" command inside my script, but it says that it's an invalid command in this case...

Well, thanks for the help!

Comment: Sounds like you need to use Expect instead of vanilla Tcl, if you need interactivity.

Comment: Although it is an old post, I'll just add some info I got in the end (though the problem still exists), in case someone has a similar problem eventually.
Mainly, plink hides text input when asking for a password. Though I sent the password programatically and never even got to see the actual plink window popping up, it looks like the text hiding effect was not restored completely. Upon returning to my program, the command window is left in some in-between state: running my software, but with the hidden text activated. Anyway, I stopped using plink, but the problem was still never solved.